# Remove a StackPanel / Grid Unwanted Default Border?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xaml, grid, stackpanel

I'm designing a UI in Visual Studio 2010, and I've come across a slight problem. I'm fairly new to XAML and this method of design, so this might be a rookie mistake. I've looked around but can't seem to find reference to a similar problem.

Basically, I have a grid with 2 rows, one of which contains a stackpanel and 5 columns. The stackpanel sits behind the columns and is used to paint the background of the entire row. When I add a background colour to the other row, I get an annoying line at the top of the stackpanel which just looks out of place. I've tried several things (showGridLines = false, transparent borders etc) but cannot seem to get rid of it. The best way to show it is through an image:

See http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/2220/tempym.jpg

One oddity I've noticed is that when I resize the window, at certain points the line disappears. Obviously this is not a solution (not least because it's going to be run full screen), but adds to the mystery of the line...

This is a trivial problem, but it is annoying me and will continue to do so until I can get rid of it, so any help would be appreciated. I've omitted the xaml for simplicity, but will post if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the oddity you noticed, try setting [`SnapsToDevicePixels`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels.aspx) to true on the grid or window.  Sounds like the borders are falling in between pixel boundaries and is being anti-aliased.

Or rather, if you're using .NET 4.0, use [`UseLayoutRounding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.uselayoutrounding.aspx) instead.

Comment: I should add that if you're using .NET 4.0 which seems to be the case, you should use [`UseLayoutRounding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.uselayoutrounding.aspx) instead.

Comment: Done. Do you recommend leaving the SnapsToDevicePixels in too?

Comment: I think you should leave out `SnapsToDevicePixels` if you will use `UseLayoutRounding`.  According to the [note in the reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels.aspx), it "is the preferred method" and would consider it as a replacement.